# Blender Mesh: Which UV Unwrapping Approach

Tags: uv

i am currently at the stage of UV Unwrapping my House model. I am very new to UV Unwrapping and am wondering how I should approach it with this model. The model in the foreground is the House in individual pieces as i initially modeled it. The one in the background is a model where all those pieces are joined into one mesh.

What i need right now is basically one Texture for every floor. I know that UV Unwrapping needs seams where you would unwrap the model into it's 2d form, but that doesn't seem very straight forward to me with this model.

Does someone have a tip ? Or maybe I need to provide additional information about the model ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't use it, because I mostly do organic modeling, but I'm thinking for what you are doing, Smart UV Project might work very well. It's under the UV Mapping menu (press U in Edit Mode to bring it up). It tries to automatically unwrap your mesh without you creating any seams first. One nice thing about it is that even if you ignore all the settings and just press OK, the settings menu remains active afterwards, so you can keep tweaking the values in the fields and see updated changes to the UV map. This is great because some of those settings would be hard to understand exactly what they do based only on their descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

as you wrote, you have to select where the seams are. Also when unwrapping, if the model is simple as walls and so on, you can just select the polygons that you want to unwrap in edit mode and unwrap it, lets say by rooms, then by outside walls.

Keep the unwrapped planes clean and organized.

You don't have to unwrap everything perfectly if you would use just generated material for some object ant not textures.

I wouldn't say that this is some kind of difficult, you just have to learn by try, or check some youtube tutorial. You will get it fast.